# How can i target a specific button that i've created with a for loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

Im creating a 4 buttons with a for loop and i want to target a specific button say a button with a name of 3 and do something with it like make it invisible. Anyone have an idea as to how i could do this?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Left = x;
                b.Top = y;
                b.Width = WIDTH;
                b.Height = HEIGHT;
                b.Name = counter.ToString();

                counter++;
                x += VGAP + HEIGHT;
                this.Controls.Add(b); 
            }
```

Comment: Iterate through `this.Controls` and check which child has the name `"3"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save buttons in array (or other collection):

```
        Button[] buttons = new Button[4];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Left = x;
            b.Top = y;
            b.Width = WIDTH;
            b.Height = HEIGHT;
            b.Name = counter.ToString();

            counter++;
            x += VGAP + HEIGHT;
            this.Controls.Add(b); 
            buttons[i] = b;
        }

        //....
        button[3].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the buttons are dynamically created, you can not reference them in your code directly with the Name property.
You can store the buttons that you create in a List. And then do something with the desired button at a given index. See the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int x, y;
    private const int WIDTH = 50;
    private const int HEIGHT = 50;
    private const int VGAP = 5;
    List<Button> lstButtons = new List<Button>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Left = x;
            b.Top = y;
            b.Width = WIDTH;
            b.Height = HEIGHT;
            b.Name = counter.ToString();

            counter++;
            x += VGAP + HEIGHT;
            this.Controls.Add(b);
            lstButtons.Add(b);

        }

        DosomethingWithButton(3);
    }

    private void DosomethingWithButton(int index)
    {
        lstButtons[index].Text = "Hello";
    }
}
```